# How to Implement HTTP 'HEAD' verb for a REST API in Spring MVC?

Tags: http, rest, spring-mvc

How to implement HTTP 'HEAD' for a REST API in Spring MVC? Are there use-cases for supporting 'HEAD' verb for the REST API? I guess, one of the client use-case might be to implement polling. For e.g. refresh an object display if there is any change. This becomes important when the object that is being fetched is complex to construct on the server and is bulky. Is it common to support 'HEAD' for the REST API?

Answer (score 2):

There is support for the HEAD method integrated in Spring MVC, i.e.:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{variable}", method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getResult(@PathVariable String variable) { ... }
```

You can also find some more advanced information here:

http://axelfontaine.com/blog/http-head.html